# Show one error for both username and email when email exists in ASP.NET Identity 2.x

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When a user registers with an existing email, currently there are two errors being added by the following:

```
  var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

I do not care for username error, user name is not even part of my registermodel.  I just want it to only show one error, now I know i can the list of errors in result.Errors by looping through them and changing it based on whats in there, but it seems this is not the right way to do.